# HuggingFace: ValueError: expected sequence of length 165 at dim 1 (got 128)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to fine-tune the BERT language model on my own data. I've gone through their docs, but their tasks seem to be not quite what I need, since my end goal is embedding text. Here's my code:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast, AutoModel, TrainingArguments, Trainer
import glob
import os


base_path = '../data/'
model_name = 'bert-base-uncased'
max_length = 512
checkpoints_dir = 'checkpoints'

tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(model_name, do_lower_case=True)


def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples['text'], padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=max_length)


dataset = load_dataset('text',
        data_files={
            'train': f'{base_path}train.txt',
            'test': f'{base_path}test.txt',
            'validation': f'{base_path}valid.txt'
        }
)

print('Tokenizing data. This may take a while...')
tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
train_dataset = tokenized_dataset['train']
eval_dataset = tokenized_dataset['test']

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

training_args = TrainingArguments(checkpoints_dir)

print('Training the model...')
trainer = Trainer(model=model, args=training_args, train_dataset=train_dataset, eval_dataset=eval_dataset)
trainer.train()
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "train_lm_hf.py", line 44, in <module>
    trainer.train()
...
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py", line 130, in torch_default_data_collator
    batch[k] = torch.tensor([f[k] for f in features])
ValueError: expected sequence of length 165 at dim 1 (got 128)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I usually get this error when the lengths of the features are not equal. For you, it seems the first feature [k] has a length of 165, and it was expecting the same length for the second one. Can you check if you have features of equal lengths?

Comment: @Tareq My data is just raw text in text files, so I'm unsure how I'd change that. Perhaps something wrong in the tokenizer?

Comment: I think the data is fine, but I'm not sure why the padding keyword in the tokenizer is not doing its job. Can you check (via debugging with pdb and printing) elements of train_dataset manually and check their lengths? or provide a sample data file I can test.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I fixed this solution by changing the tokenize function to:

```
def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples['text'], padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=max_length)
```

(note the `padding` argument). Also, I used a data collator like so:

```
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=True, mlm_probability=0.15
)
trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        data_collator=data_collator,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=eval_dataset
)
```

Comment: Worked for me thanks.  But what is the source of the problem?  Is the data being tokenized too long for the given model?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked for me.

I am a bit confused. Data Collator is used for dynamic padding based on the batch level and hence we generally dont add `padding` in the tokenize_function when we use Data Collator.

I will revisit the data collator documentation to find this out.