# HuggingFace: ValueError:expected sequence of length 21 at dim 1 (got 20)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am fine-tuning InCoder for code generation on my own data. To do so, I've gone through the tutorials in all implementations - Trainer, Pytorch and Tensorflow but cannot seem to make any of them work. I've seen this post [HuggingFace: ValueError: expected sequence of length 165 at dim 1 (got 128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71166789/huggingface-valueerror-expected-sequence-of-length-165-at-dim-1-got-128) but my padding is within trainer as a method. I'm also not using a masked language model to mitigate likewise. Here, I'm testing on 1% of the data. This is my code to reproduce the error for `trainer`:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("ablam/gcode")

# Tokenize texts with same vocab as training the model
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

# Preserve casing info
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/incoder-1B",use_fast=True,do_lower_case=False)

# Tokenize our texts.
def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["text"], truncation=True)

# In batches and 4 processes to speed it up. 
tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True, num_proc=4)

# Postprocess 1: remove texts
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.remove_columns(['text'])

# Postprocess 2: Add label column 
# Labels = ground truth for the model to learn from.

def new_column(example):
    example["labels"] = example["input_ids"].copy()
    return example

tokenized_datasets_label = tokenized_datasets.map(new_column, batched=True, num_proc=4)

# Postprocess 3: 1% of data
import datasets 

train_dataset, train_1percent_label = tokenized_datasets_label['train'].train_test_split(test_size=0.01).values() #(41297976, 3)
test_dataset, test_1percent_label = tokenized_datasets_label['test'].train_test_split(test_size=0.01).values() #(417152, 3)

# Postprocess 4: token_type_ids is not considered in model.
train_1percent_trainer = train_1percent.remove_columns(['token_type_ids'])
test_1percent_trainer = test_1percent.remove_columns(['token_type_ids'])

# Trainer
from transformers import TrainingArguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer")

import numpy as np
from datasets import load_metric

metric = load_metric("accuracy")

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)

from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer

training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer", evaluation_strategy="epoch")

from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("facebook/incoder-1B")

import torch 
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_1percent_trainer,
    eval_dataset=test_1percent_trainer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    optimizers=[torch.optim.AdamW, torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR]
)

trainer.train()
```

My error is as follows:

```
~/.conda/envs/deep_gcode/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py in torch_default_data_collator(features)
    128                 batch[k] = torch.stack([f[k] for f in features])
    129             else:
--> 130                 batch[k] = torch.tensor([f[k] for f in features])
    131 
    132     return batch

ValueError: expected sequence of length 21 at dim 1 (got 20)
```

When I saw this, I tried batching but it's not a parameter to `trainer`. How can I go about this?

Comment: Have you found any solution for it? Im having a similar problem